# How to a flash the rom.zip file to my Android phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware

I extracted the rom.zip from the HTC RUU installation and I want to flash it to my phone.

In case it matters, it is an HTC Desire HD, rooted with Cyanomod and ClockMod Recovery on it.

All I want is to flash the original stock firmware back to the phone. Because the phone has now a different firmware RUU will not recognise it.

What I need to do?

PS. I tried to rename the file to PB32IMG.zip and use the update from zip option but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> PS. I tried to rename the file to PB32IMG.zip and use the update from zip option but it doesn't work.

How does it not work? Please provide details.

---

**The general procedure for installing a new ROM would be:**

1. Download ROM .zip file to SD card.
2. Back up current ROM in case new ROM does not work:

   - Boot to Recovery Mode (hold down the Power and Volume Down (Vol -) keys at the same time under boot)
   - Select 'backup and restore'
   - Select 'Backup' and confirm
   - wait for process to finish and go back to Recovery main screen
3. Wipe and factory reset (this is important for stability! Especially when installing a different ROM, and not just an update. With an update you can usually skip factory reset):

   - Select “wipe data/factory reset” and confirm
   - Select “advanced” then “wipe dalvik cache” and confirm
   - wait for process to finish and go back to Recovery main screen
4. Install ROM.

   - Select “install ZIP from SD Card“
   - Select “choose zip from sdcard“
   - Select the .zip file you downloaded to the SD card in step 1.
   - Wait for process to finish, go back to Recovery main screen and select Reboot.

**Where in the above process do you get stuck?**